# Черв'як та хробак – це два повних синоніми, чи один з них русизм?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, росіянізм, синоніми

У багатьох джерелах ці два слова вказуються як синоніми. Наприклад, [вікі](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8), а також в словниках синонімів, [наприклад](https://xn--h1aaldafs6o.xn--j1amh/%D0%A7/%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D0%BA) або [тут](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53413/275402.html). Але **черв'як** є дуже близьке до російського **червяк**, а **хробак** широко вживається в сільській місцевості і не має окремих смислових відтінків, якщо я не помиляюсь. Чи не є **черв'як** русизмом?

Comment: Цікаво! Я вважав, що хробак - це обов'язково личинка комахи. Грінченко подає як синонім черв'яка.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Словник Фасмера [каже](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fie%2Fvasmer&text_number=+16383&encoding=utf-rus), що *червь* походить від праслов'янського кореня ***čьrvь** і є спорідненим із словами *червоний*, *червувати* (фарбувати).

А значить, слово *черв'як* має старовинне походження і тому точно не є русизмом.

Comment: Було б мабудь цікаво. Просто ті джерела, що знаходив я не розрізняють ці слова за смислом.

Comment: @AlexSodin, ну, з точки зору [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/cherv.jak)-[11](http://sum.in.ua/s/khrobak), це не повні синоніми.

Comment: @Sasha в якому місці не синоніми? У обох слів є значення "личинка", та у хробака зазначено, що те ж саме, що й черв'як...

Comment: @SassaNF, у черв'яка ще є «4. Зубчасте колесо…», у хробака ще є «4. перен., діал. Маленька дитина». Крім того, не знаю, наскільки це суттєво, але все ж «черв'як» першим подає все ж черв'як, а у «хробака» першим йде саме гусінь («личинка комах, яка живе в землі»).

Comment: @Sasha До "зубчатого колеса": "черв'як" використовується у назві "черв'ячна передача" - https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0

Comment: Наявність слова в праслов'янській необов'язково свідчить про його збереження в українській протягом усього часу — скажімо, слово могло зникнути в українській і перезапозичитися з російської.

Answer (score 6):

Наскільки я можу зрозуміти, залежить від регіону. В західних областях «хробак» використовується як замінник «черв'яка» (який там, схоже, не вживається). У центрально-східних, «черв'як» — це дощовий черв'як (чи будь-яка інша червоподібна тварина), «хробак» — переважно личинка хруща та деяких інших комах (хоча гусінь хробаками не називають).

Р.Ѕ. СУМ-11 та ЕСУМ для слова «хробак» наводять значення «личинка комах, яка живе в землі» та «черв'як».

ЕСУМ виводить слово «хробак» від праслов'янського зі значенням «жук, личинка» (але не «черв'як»). Водночас, у польській robak має основне значення «черв'як». Звідси можна зробити висновок, що значення «личинка» чи «черв'як» у тому чи іншому регіоні України має корелювати із впливом польської мови.

> **хроба́к** «личинка комах, яка живе в землі; черв'як, робак», [*хорба́к*] Нед, [*хроб*] «хробак», *хроба́цтво*, [*хроба́чник*] «лікарська рослина, вживана від глистів», *хробачня́*, [*хробова́тка*] «кружниця, Turbo Rugosus» Нед, [*хро́бство*] «хробацтво» ВеБ, *хроба́чливий*, *хроба́чний*; — п. robak, [chrobak] «черв'як», ч. chrobak (ент.) «гнояк, гнойовик», слц. chrobák «жук»; — псл. xrobakъ «жук, личинка», що є суфіксальним утворенням від псл. xrobati «гризти з хрускотом; хрускотіти» звуконаслідувального походження; існує бездоказове припущення (Machek ESJČ 206) про спорідненість із гр. *σκάραβος* «рогатий жук» і *κάραβος* «краб; різновид рогатого жука»; думка про польське джерело для укр. *хроба́к* (Bern. I 403; Richhardt 57) не має підстав. — ЭССЯ 8, 99; Sławski I 79; Brückner 184, 459; Doroszewski PF 13, 203. — Пор. **хро́бот.**

Comment: Дуже цікава думка. Тобто в західних областях «хробак» використовується в усіх значеннях («черв'як» рідко використовують), а у центрально-східних — диференціація за значенням (основним для слова), — я правильно зрозумів?

Comment: Шкода, що буде **ду-у-же** важко знайти докази для цього. Але думка дуже цікава. (Якби хтось перелопатив літературу письменників із різних областей, щоби знайти докази для цього, але це неп'ятихвилинна справа…)

Comment: [СУМ-11: хробак](http://sum.in.ua/s/khrobak) — першим значенням подається личинка (зокрема, личинка хруща, як це видно з прикладів), другим — черв'к. Проте, у звичному мені варіанті усної української (Черкащина) дощових черв'яків називають лише черв'яками, а хробаками — лише личинок хруща.

Comment: Так, особистий досвід. Але, на жаль, особисті враження за своєю природою непевні (одному жителю міста М., наприклад, здається, що слово с. уживається здебільшого в цьому значенні, а іншому жителю того ж міста М. — що в іншому). Але в будь-якому разі це дуже цікава інформація.

Comment: СУМ-11, проте, підтверджує семантичну різницю між «черв'яком» та «хробаком» принаймні в частині діалектів. Для випадку, коли «хробак» позначає «черв'яка» взагалі, нема потреби виділяти з нього «личинку», яка також червоподібна, а отже, ймовірно, хробак-личинка і хробак-черв'як належать до різних діалектів. Логічно?

Comment: Я не розумію, чому Вам поставили мінус. Адже думку Ви висунули дуже цікаву (і, можливо, правильну) думку. Але, ні, доведення нелогічне, в СУМ-11: «хробак» — (1) «безхребетна тварина» // «личинка»; «хробак» — (1) «личинка», (2) «= черв'як 1»; так, я помітив, що в різному порядку визначення йдуть; але формально це не доводить навіть різницю в значеннях, не кажучи вже про залежність від діалекту (ІМХО).

Comment: Оце вже цікаво! Тобто з одного боку походить від псл. _xrobakъ_ «жук, личинка», отже ймовірно, хоч у якохось регіонах першим має зберегтися первісне значення «личинка», а з іншого — у Польщі воно означає саме черв'як (отже можна припустити якийсь діалектний градієнт ([діалектний континуум](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Діалектний_континуум)) між ними). Подивимось, як відреагують інші, хоча, боюся, на жаль, не багато хто витрачає час на переоцінення вже оцінених відповідей.

Answer (score 3):

Дореволюційний словник Грінченка подає синонімічні значення:

[Черв'як](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/64502-chervjak.html#show_point) = червак = червякъ

[Хробак](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/63296-khrobak.html#show_point) = робак = червякъ